# 2013 Workflow intermittently Failed To Start

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

we have a intermittently error happening on one of our workflows, and we haven't been able to reproduce it.

and the only Outcome we receive 
Workflow Cancelled
System Account
Workflow "workflow name" was canceled by System Account.

The workflow is a simple workflow, the only thing it does is send an email to a list of users

Comment: How many users does it sends the mail to?

Comment: 3 users, AD user accounts, all visible to the submitting users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this was because of our environment blocking external execution and thus blocking SP Workflows

Answer (score 0):

Don't start workflow with system account. Start workflow with another user.

Clear SharePoint Designer cache:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/how-to-clear-your-sharepoint-designer-20102013-cache/

Comment: the workflows are terminated by the System Account because the workflow is unable to start, that's why it "Fails at start" , the workflows are started with an user account with contribute rights to the list and the site. 

why would i need to clear the SPD cache when the error is in the sp online server ?